# How to output when reading a binary file?

Tags: c++, fstream, iostream

I have a binary file already created which is "index.dat". It simply contains a list of integers. I want to check the last integer present in the file. For this, I position the file pointer at the last integer and read it. Currently, my file has integers from 0 to 4, but the output is always 6.

How do I solve this problem?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   int i;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("index.dat",ios::binary|ios::in);
    if(infile.is_open())
    {   infile.seekg(sizeof(i),ios::end);
        infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&i),sizeof(i));
        cout<<i;
    }
    infile.close();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample input file, please?

Comment: You are trying to seek to `sizeof(i)` bytes *past* end of file. This of course fails. The subsequent `read` also fails, and then you print uninitialized variable. When seeking from end, you need a negative offset.

Answer (score 0):

Igor Tandetnik has made this clear in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57021284/how-to-output-when-reading-a-binary-file#comment100573074_57021284):

> You are trying to seek to `sizeof(i)` bytes *past* end of file. This
>   of course fails. The subsequent `read` also fails, and then you print
>   uninitialized variable. When seeking from end, you need a negative
>   offset. — Igor Tandetnik 18 hours ago

So instead of

```
infile.seekg(sizeof(i),ios::end);
```

You need to do something like

```
infile.seekg(-static_cast<streamoff>(sizeof(i)), ios_base::end);
```

(The cast to `streamoff` is to make sure we don't apply `-` on an unsigned value, resulting in a very big positive value.  `streamoff` is signed, and `ifstream::off_type` is guaranteed to be `streamoff`.)